# How to convert strings to array of byte and back

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

4I must write strings to a binary MIDI file. The standard requires one to know the length of the string in bytes. As I want to write for mobile as well I cannot use AnsiString, which was a good way to ensure that the string was a one-byte string. That simplified things. I tested the following code:

```
TByte = array of Byte;

function TForm3.convertSB (arg: string): TByte;
var
   i: Int32;
begin
   Label1.Text := (SizeOf (Char));
   for i := Low (arg) to High (arg) do
   begin
      label1.Text := label1.Text + ' ' + IntToStr (Ord (arg [i]));
   end;
end; // convert SB //

convertSB ('MThd');
```

It returns 2 77 84 104 100 (as label text) in Windows as well as Android. Does this mean that Delphi treats strings by default as UTF-8? This would greatly simplify things but I couldn't find it in the help. And what is the best way to convert this to an array of bytes? Read each character and test whether it is 1, 2 or 4 bytes and allocate this space in the array? For converting back to a character: just read the array of bytes until a byte is encountered < 128?

Comment: @Tlama - That was on purpose :-) When writing a MIDI file I can just organize that that is the case. I wondered what Delphi was doing when using just UTF-8 characters, would it automatically change that to a representation of two bytes? It does not and -interestingly- it does so consistently for Windows and Android.

Comment: actually the characters in you code in the question are indeed two bytes wide. That's what the call to SizeOf told you.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Delphi strings are encoded internally as UTF-16. There was a big clue in the fact that `SizeOf(Char)` is 2.

The reason that all your characters had ordinal in the ASCII range is that UTF-16 extends ASCII in the sense that characters 0 to 127, in the ASCII range, have the same ordinal value in UTF-16. And all your characters are ASCII characters.

That said, you do not need to worry about the internal storage. You simply convert between string and byte array using the [`TEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding) class. For instance, to convert to UTF-8 you write:

```
bytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

And in the opposite direction:

```
str := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

The class supports many other encodings, as described in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding_Properties). It's not clear from the question which encoding you are need to use. Hopefully you can work the rest out from here.

Comment: I want to read and write the file solely in UTF-8 which you already guessed. TEncoding is a great class that solves a lot of my string format questions. My question was inspired by the fear that I had to do al the encoding myself, hence the question about the internal representation.