# Byte to String in Delphi

Tags: c#, string, delphi, byte

I want to convert a Byte to String in Delphi

in c# for example is:

```
Convert.ToString(Byte, 16);
```

I tried:

```
SetString(AnsiStr, PAnsiChar(@ByteArray[0]), LengthOfByteArray);
StringVar := Chr(ByteVar);
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert strings to array of byte and back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442665/how-to-convert-strings-to-array-of-byte-and-back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use this function;

```
function TForm1.bintostr(const bin: array of byte): string;
const HexSymbols = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 2*Length(bin));
  for i :=  0 to Length(bin)-1 do begin
    Result[1 + 2*i + 0] := HexSymbols[1 + bin[i] shr 4];
    Result[1 + 2*i + 1] := HexSymbols[1 + bin[i] and $0F];
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This bears little relation to the C# code. It is inelegant with the use of 1 based indexing. It replicates the system function BinToHex. Making a general function be a member of a form class is poor design. In short there is little to commend this to future visitors.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `Byte` is a placeholder for a value of type `byte`, your C# code converts a **single byte** to its hexadecimal representation. The Delphi equivalent is [`IntToHex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.IntToHex).

```
var
  s: string;
  b: Byte;
....
b := ...;
s := IntToHex(b);
```

---

Your Delphi code hints at you actually wishing to convert an **array of bytes** to their hexadecimal representation. In which case the function you need is [`BinToHex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.BinToHex). I can't really give you much more detail because your question itself was lacking in detail. Without knowledge of the types of the variables, we are left making guesses. In future questions, it would be wise to supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).