# How can I convert a 4-byte string into an unicode emoji?

Tags: delphi, encoding

A webservice i use in my Delphi 10.3 returns a string to me consisting of these four bytes: F0 9F 99 82 . I expect a slightly smiling emoji. [This](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+1F642) site shows this byte sequence as the UTF-8 representation of that emoji. So I guess i have a UTF-8 representation in my string, but its an actual unicode string? How do i convert my string into the actual unicode representation, to show it, for example, in a TMemo?

Comment: That's not a "_4 byte string_" - it's **one** character expressed in 4 bytes as of UTF-8. Use [`TEncoding.UTF8.GetString( my_bytes )`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding.GetString) then.

Comment: Thank you, that did work. You should repost this as a possible solution, so i can accept it.

Comment: How do I get the byte array in the first place? I guess TEncoding.XXX.GetBytes(InputString), but I dont know what to insert for XXX. I only have the string variable filled by the webservice available, not an actual byte array.

Comment: So the related Qs on the right side like [How to convert strings to array of byte and back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21442665/4299358) don't answer that for you? Should your Q include actual code so we see how everything looks in the first place? Are you sure you don't want to create a new separate Q?

Comment: Indeed it does. I didnt notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character  has the [Unicode **code point**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Codespace_and_Code_Points) U+1F642. Displaying text is defined thru an encoding: how a set of bytes has to be interpreted:

- in [UTF-**8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) one character can consist of **8**, 16, 24 or 32 bits (1 to 4 `Byte`s); this one is `$F0 $9F $99 $82`.
- in [UTF-**16**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) one character can consist of **16** or 32 bits (2 or 4 bytes = 1 or 2 `Word`s); this one is `$D83D $DE42` (using [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U+010000_to_U+10FFFF)).
- in [UTF-**32**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) one character always consists of **32** bits (4 bytes = 1 `Cardinal` or `DWord`) and always equals to the **code point**, that is `$1F642`.

In Delphi, you can use:

- [`TEncoding.UTF8.GetString()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding.GetString) for **UTF-8**
- (or `TEncoding.Unicode.GetString()` if you'd have UTF-16LE
- and `TEncoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString()` if you'd have UTF-16BE).

Keep in mind that  is just a character like each letter, symbol and whitespace of this text: it can be marked thru selection (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and copied to the clipboard (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). No special care is needed.

Comment: If you know that the received text is UTF-8 encoded, another option would be to put the raw bytes into a `UTF8String`, and then just assign that to a normal `String`. The RTL will handle the conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16 (Delphi's native string encoding) for you.